# JavaScript Conditional shortcut. More then one else if

Tags: javascript

Can we have more then one else if statement using the conditional shortcut.

```
var x = this.checked ? y : z;
```

Comment: You can have as many as you want. Do you understand how a ternary operator works?

Comment: How can you even ***ask*** this question? You know that `this.checked` delivers a boolean answer and I ask you: how many choices are available in the result of the conditioal? Hint: two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible. In programming it is called nesting.Consider this example.

```
hasMac = false;
hasLinux = false;
var x = hasMac ? "Mac User" : hasLinux ? "Linux user" : "User OS Unknown"; 
// x will be "User OS Unknown"

hasMac = false;
hasLinux = true;
var x = hasMac ? "Mac User" : hasLinux ? "Linux user" : "User OS Unknown"; 
// x will be "Linux user"

hasMac = true;
hasLinux = true; // or false, won't matter
var x = hasMac ? "Mac User" : hasLinux ? "Linux user" : "User OS Unknown"; 
// x will be "Mac user"
```

Comment: @Pinkie, still as many others have suggested use it sparingly - when you are sure it will not dent the readability !!

Answer (score 5):

You can abuse the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator), since it evaluates both its operands and returns the second one:

```
var x = this.checked ? y : doSomething(), doSomethingElse(), z;
```

However, that makes the code less readable (and maintainable) than the corresponding `if` statement:

```
var x;
if (this.checked) {
    x = y;
} else {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
    x = z;
}
```

So I would recommend using an `if` statement in your case.

Answer (score 4):

No, a ternary operator returns one of two expressions based on a boolean expression.

You *can* nest them, if you really want to, but it's confusing and hard to read:

`var x = a ? b ? c : d : e`

Comment: Adding brackets might helps but I do agree, in these cases using `switch` or several `if` statements is more readable.

Comment: @Hamish Can you explain how this works. The way i read it is (if a then b, if c else d else e).

Comment: if a then (if b then c else d) else e

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but you can have several nested statements:

```
var x = this.checked ? y : (some_other_condition) ? z : z2;
```

Answer (score 1):

do u mean `else if`?

if so then you can go like

```
var x = this.checked ? y : this.elseifcheck ? z : a;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean like:

```
var x = this.checked ? y : z : a;
```

The answer is no. But you ***can*** have a production like:

```
var x = this.checked ? y : ( z > 1 ? z : a );
```